# Intellij IDEA plugin for saving Java -> HTML?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pretty-print

Is there an IDEA plugin for pretty printing (or save/export) Java to syntax colored HTML?  Failing that, what's your favorite web site for that?

**EDIT**: I have a Java program, I want to convert the source code to HTML so that I can display it on the web.  As I will be making lots of edits to the source, it would be handy to be able to convert it directly to HTML within IDEA.

Comment: Please clarify - Java to HTML?  Do you mean javadocs?  And how do you expect color information to be communicated and interpreted by all other programs reading the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one: http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=3828

Comment: +1 - Thanks.  I'm an IntelliJ user, but I've never used that plug-in.  Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ does this (well, v7 does).  File|Export to html

Comment: Exactly. This feature exists in IntelliJ since ages ~ 2001 (so no need for a plug-in to achieve that)