# java source code to html with links from uses to definitions

Tags: java, html, documentation

A tool (preferably free or open source) that converts java source code to html with proper links from uses of identifiers to their definitions.

Comment: See similar intellij question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162537/intellij-idea-plugin-for-saving-java-html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [java2html.com](http://www.java2html.com/) - seems pretty close to what you want. It's GPL so you could perhaps tweak it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[Javadoc](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/javadoc/index.jsp) is the tool you are looking for. The fact that it is easily expandable, should suit your needs quite well. As an example the [FAQ provides](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/javadoc/faq/index.html#sourcedoclet) how you can basically edit the standard doc. Now this isn't exactly what you want, but by expanding Javadoc you should be able to produce the results you want.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you elaborate how javadoc can be used to format java _source_ code the way OP wants?

Answer (score 0):

I think http://www.java2html.com/ will do what you need. An Ant task is included:

```
    <taskdef name="java2html" classname="com.java2html.Java2HTMLTask"
             classpathref="cp"/>
    <property name="html.src.dir" value="demos/main/war/src"/>
    <mkdir dir="${html.src.dir}"/>
    <java2html destination="${html.src.dir}" header="false" footer="false">
        <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>
    </java2html>
```